# Encode 23 char string into 9 char string and then decode it back univocally

Tags: string, algorithm, decode, encode

How can i encode a string like 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv into a 9 char string and then decode it back univocally?

In fact my entry string is a random combination of the character included in the example, i wanna find a way to shorten it in string form and then decode it back univocally.

Answer (score 2):

In the character set "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv", there are 32 different characters.

There are 32^23 (approximately 4 * 10^34) different strings that are 23 characters long, and composed exclusively of the above characters.

There are 256^9 (approximately 4 * 10^21) different strings that are 9 characters long, and composed of any combination of ASCII characters.

4e34 is much larger than 4e21, so by the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), there is no way to losslessly compress the first kind of string into the second kind of string, and no way to unambiguously decode the second kind into the first.

---

Although you can't compress it that far, *some* compression is still possible. You can get about 5/8ths improvement by bit packing.

Start by converting your characters into numbers. ex. h is the 17th number in your character set, so it becomes 17.

```
hello
[17, 14, 21, 21, 24]
```

Convert your numbers to binary. Remember to pad each value to five bits.

```
[17, 14, 21, 21, 24]
[10001, 01110, 10101, 10101, 11000]
```

Combine the binary into one big value.

```
[10001, 01110, 10101, 10101, 11000]
1000101110101011010111000
```

Split the value into sections eight digits long.

```
1000101110101011010111000
1 00010111 01010110 10111000
```

Convert each section into decimal.

```
1 00010111 01010110 10111000
[1, 23, 86, 184]
```

Convert each number into its corresponding ASCII value.

```
[1, 23, 86, 184]
['\x01', '\x17', 'V', '\xb8']
```

Now you've compressed your five character sequence "hello" into the four character sequence "\x01\x17V\xb8'".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even bit packing isn't the right solution, cause the encoded string should be human writable and readable.
So '\x01', '\x17', '\xb8' does not fulfill this request @Kevin

Comment: You could change "Split the value into sections eight digits long" to "Split the value into sections six digits long", and turn each resulting number into the Nth printable ASCII character. but then you're only getting 5/6ths compression, so it's barely worth doing.